# how to delete totally the value in searchbar using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, api

I am having an issue in removing the value in my search bar since this is a filter, I  need to delete a value when I wanted to search another one, but I'm troubled in deleting the value. this my function

```
$("#sid1").click(function(){
$("#Vsid").hide();
$('#txtsid').val("");
```

i attached a picture of my sample api

[/api/public/2ndlayer/search/33/avone/barcode/gender/producttype/productname](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFcIu.png)

My HTML:

```
<div id="Vsid" style=" float:right; background-color: pink; " ng-show="sid" >
  <b >SCP ID : {{ sid }} </b> 
  <button id="sid1" ng-click="reset()"> >x</button>
</div>

<input type="text" id="txtsid" style="width: 70%; margin-left:2px;" ng-model="sid" class="input-group inline form-control" placeholder="SCP ID" ng-required="true" required>
<button id="scpid1" class="btn btn-primary">ADD</button>
```

Comment: can you include the portion of html that your code above addresses?  Thanks

Comment: `.val("")` isn't working? What is the problem exactly? And post some HTML.

Comment: this is the htm       l ` <div id="Vsid" style=" float:right; background-color: pink; " ng-show="sid" >   
<b >SCP ID :  {{  sid }} </b>
<button id="sid1" ng-click="reset()"> >x</button> </div>` `<input type="text" id="txtsid" style="width: 70%; margin-left:2px;" ng-model="sid" class="input-group inline form-control" placeholder="SCP ID"  ng-required="true" required>
               <button id="scpid1" class="btn btn-primary">ADD</button>` @louys @arcee123

Comment: With this HTML, I can now say that your jQuery code should work... If you close the function with `});`. Do you have some error in console?

Comment: @louys yes i still committing error, its still doesn't resetting the value in console

Comment: This code works fine. Look on [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/vZdRYR). Look [**at the console**](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers/77337#77337). If there is some errors, post them here.

Comment: ` /api/public/2ndlayer/search/41/1/barcode/gender/producttype/productname `   --> this what the result in my API when i clicked the search button, it happens when i wanted to search only 41, and 1 still shows, thats why it shows error.

Comment: reference is in the picture above

Comment: i already solved it, with another function, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

onfocus you can remove the value from your search filter because whenever you want to search new field you will focus on it and when focused it will be empty.